# Include directive reference not resolved in Eclipse when compiling OpenCV Core module for Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, makefile, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile the OpenCV 2.4.9 core module (c++ source) for Android.  I'm trying to do this using Eclipse/Android NDK on Windows 8 (64-bit machine).  I've made a slight modification to the OpenCV core module (c++ code) and want to build/test it out on android.  Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Create a new Android library project (File -> New -> Project ... -> Android Application Project)
- Check the "Mark this project as a library" option
- Once created, add native support (right-click project and choose Android Tools -> Add Native Support ...)
- Delete the default cpp file from the jni folder
- Add **Application-14.mk** file
- Modify **Android.mk** file

**Application-14.mk** file contents:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

**Android.mk** file contents:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LINKED_FILES_SRC := ../../../Shared/OpenCV249/modules/core

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_core

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/tables.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/system.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/stat.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/rand.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/persistence.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/parallel.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/out.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/opengl_interop_deprecated.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/opengl_interop.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/matrix.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/matop.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/matmul.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/mathfuncs.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/lapack.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/gpumat.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/glob.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/dxt.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/drawing.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/datastructs.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/copy.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/convert.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/cmdparser.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/array.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/arithm.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/alloc.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(LINKED_FILES_SRC)/src/algorithm.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here's the output when I try to build

```
C:\droidev\android-ndk-r10c\ndk-build.cmd -w all 
make.exe: Entering directory `C:/Projects/Enterprise/MobileServices/UM/Android/opencv_core'
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: opencv_core <= tables.cpp
In file included from jni/../../../Shared/OpenCV249/modules/core/src/tables.cpp:49:0:
jni/../../../Shared/OpenCV249/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:48:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
make.exe: Leaving directory `C:/Projects/Enterprise/MobileServices/UM/Android/opencv_core'
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/opencv_core/__/__/__/Shared/OpenCV249/modules/core/src/tables.o] Error 1
```

Here's the location of the files referenced in the output above.

```
C:\Projects\Enterprise\MobileServices\UM\Shared\OpenCV249\modules\core\include\opencv2\core\core.hpp
C:\Projects\Enterprise\MobileServices\UM\Shared\OpenCV249\modules\core\src\precomp.hpp
C:\Projects\Enterprise\MobileServices\UM\Shared\OpenCV249\modules\core\src\tables.cpp
```

Here's the line in `precomp.hpp` that is related to the error:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

So `core.hpp` can't be found because it's not in `opencv2/core/core.hpp` **in relation to precomp.hpp**. I normally work in Visual Studio, and when you configure include directories for c++ projects, it behaves differently (e.g. The error above wouldn't occur if I included `C:\Projects\Enterprise\MobileServices\UM\Shared\OpenCV249\modules\core\include` as an additional include directory). I've tried moving the files around (and copies of the files), but because of the way the include directives are in the OpenCV source files, I run into other errors after resolving this particular one. I've also tried every combination I can think of for the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable as it relates to the include directory.

Does anyone know how I can better describe where to search for included files/directories in my makefile?  Should I be configuring includes differently somehow in my makefile?  Anyone know how to get the "Visual Studio like" include functionality that I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to compile after the following corrections:

- Convert relative paths to absolute paths in **Android.mk**
- Rename **Application-14.mk** to **Application.mk**
- Add remaining dependencies (zlib, liblog, and dynamic cuda includes)

Here's **Android.mk** with all the changes (this compiled for me, BUT I haven't tested out the library yet):

```
##############################################################
# Setup Paths
##############################################################
LOCAL_PATH      := $(call my-dir)
APP_PROJECT_PATH:= $(realpath .)
CORE_ROOT       := $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/../../Shared/OpenCV249/modules/core
DYNAMICCUDA_ROOT:= $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/../../Shared/OpenCV249/modules/dynamicuda
ZLIB_ROOT       := $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/../../Shared/OpenCV249/3rdparty/zlib

##############################################################
# zlib module configuration
##############################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := zlib

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/zlib

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(ZLIB_ROOT)/adler32.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/compress.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/crc32.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/deflate.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/gzclose.c 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/gzlib.c 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/gzread.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/gzwrite.c 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/infback.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/inffast.c  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/inflate.c 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/inftrees.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/trees.c 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/uncompr.c 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(ZLIB_ROOT)/zutil.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

##############################################################
# opencv_core module configuration
##############################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_core

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := zlib

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= $(CORE_ROOT)/src
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= $(CORE_ROOT)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= $(DYNAMICCUDA_ROOT)/src
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= $(DYNAMICCUDA_ROOT)/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CORE_ROOT)/src/algorithm.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/alloc.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/arithm.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/array.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/cmdparser.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/convert.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/copy.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/datastructs.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/drawing.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/dxt.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/gl_core_3_1.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/glob.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/gpumat.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/lapack.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/mathfuncs.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/matmul.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/matop.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/matrix.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/opengl_interop.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/opengl_interop_deprecated.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/out.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/parallel.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/persistence.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/rand.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/stat.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/system.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CORE_ROOT)/src/tables.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```